# Delay knockout binding evaluation

Tags: jquery-mobile, knockout.js

Knockout newbie here. I have a page to display the customer info.

```
1st div should be displayed when customer info is present.
2nd div should be displayed when no customers are displayed

//1st Div
<div id="custInfoList" data-role="content"
    data-bind="foreach: customers, visible : customers().length > 0">
    <p data-bind="text: $data.info"></p>
</div>
//2nd Div
<div id="empty" data-role="content"
    data-bind="visible: customers().length === 0 ">
    <p>No Customer Information</p>
</div>
```

My model is like this:

```
var myModel = {
    customers : ko.observableArray();
}
```

..and on page load I am adding this logic:

```
//On Page Load, call AJAX to populate the customers
    //customers = {jsonData}
```

My page is using jQuery Mobile. My only problem is when the page is first displayed, the second div is displayed.  When the Ajax json data returns, that's where it is hidden.

Is it possible to hide the second div while the ajax is still on loading and data has not yet returned?

**UPDATE 2**

On a related note, I tried the KO HTML template which I just read from the net

```
<!-- ko if: customers().length -->
    <div id="custInfoList" data-role="content"
        data-bind="foreach: customers, visible : customers().length > 0">
        <p data-bind="text: $data.info"></p>
    </div>
<!-- /ko -->
<div id="empty" data-role="content"
    data-bind="if: customers().length === 0">
    <p>No Customer Information</p>
</div>
```

but still unsuccessful. Any thoughts what is missing?

**UPDATE 3**
I tried updating what @shriek demonstrated in his fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/t0wgLt79/17/

```
<!-- ko if: customers() -->
<div id="custInfoList" data-role="content" data-bind="foreach: customers">
    <p data-bind="text: $data"></p>
</div>
<!-- /ko -->
<div id="empty" data-role="content" data-bind="if: customers().length === 0" style="display: none;">
    <p>No Customer Information</p>
</div>
<button data-bind="click:popCustomers">Populate</button>
```

My JS:

```
$.support.cors = true;
var test = {
    customers: ko.observableArray(),
    popCustomers: function () {
        for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            this.customers.push(i);
        }
    },
    popByAjax: function () {
        console.log("Calling JSON...");
        $.getJSON("http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?id=2172797", function (data) {
            console.log(data);
            if (data.sys) {
                this.customers.push(data.sys.country);
                console.log("Loaded");
            }
        }.bind(this));
    }
};
test.popByAjax();
ko.applyBindings(Object.create(test));
```

On initial load, the "AU" is displayed. Now change the weather?id=2172797 into weather?id=21727971 to make it invalid. I notice that the no customer information is **not** displayed.

Comment: add `style="display: none"` to your 2nd div. Then when the AJAX calls returns, `$('#empty').show()`

Comment: Hi James thanks, that is what I used to do in Jquery. I was thinking if Knockout js has some sort of way for this since they offered the "visible" binding then somehow I thought it is being evaluated.  Otherwise, I can remove the "visible" and rely on Jquery DOM manipulation.

Comment: Well the problem is that before the customers are returned, the length IS zero, so that binding is explicitly showing the div. I think what you're trying to do is outside the scope of Knockout, so I would use jQuery to do it.

Comment: Yes, exactly.  That's the same thought that I have.  I just asked this if somehow there is a way.  I tried using knockout template but I cant seem to make it work as well.

Comment: This is not just related to knockout but to all the async programming. What I would do for this sort of thing is have some kind of spinner or 'Loading' text to display when fetching the data (You can also put an overlay of the spinner with `css` class.) And then hide the spinner/loader after you're done with fetching your data. Knockout should have `css` binding too. `data-bind={css: overlay : customer().length === 0}`

Comment: On Update 2:- That's pretty much what I was going for. :)

Comment: About Update 2, I tried it but it seems not working as expected.  I am not sure why upto now.

Comment: I add a `loading: ko.observable(true)` to my view model, set it to `false` after you populate your array, and on the page use `data-bind="visible: !loading() && customers().length === 0"`

Comment: @MarkEstrada Remember, `customer()` has to be an `observable`. If it's just a plain function then knockout will have no idea when it's value changes.

Comment: @shriek, yes I declared that one as an observablearray.

Comment: Should be working. Although, it's not an ajax call like yours but this is similar to what you have got. http://jsfiddle.net/t0wgLt79/

Comment: @shriek,  Can you check my Update 3?

Comment: Okay..I see now. First and foremost, you don't need `style:none` if you're doing `if` from `ko` `KO` automatically does that for you. And another thing that you have to keep in mind is that you should empty your `observableArray` if you don't get any response back. Remember, you're checking if that `observableArary` is empty or not. Here's a fiddle with some modification http://jsfiddle.net/4hmqdsup/ You can go ahead and ask any questions that you have on the code.

Comment: @shriek Excellent!  Now I dont know how to make your comment the correct answer just to close my question.  If ever you have the time, can you make your comment an answer to my question so that I could flagged it as the correct answer? Many thanks.

Comment: @MarkEstrada Okay, done. Glad I could help. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comment above, for Update 3 `display:none` is extraneous as it's already being taken care by `if` on the data-bind.

Second thing is the `observableArray` had to be emptied after receiving bad response because hiding/displaying is based on the comparison of that `observableArray`'s length.

Code to fiddle with:-
http://jsfiddle.net/4hmqdsup/

Answer (score 1):

you see the second div as well as the first div because the knockout `applyBinding` to your DOM elements, has not yet been occurred, which means the `visible` binding has not yet been evaluated, and therefore no element will be hidden accordingly, leaving it in its default state ( which is to be shown )

to overcome this behaviour, you only need to add a `style="display: none;"` to those elements you want them to be hidden by default, and then the `visible` binding will remove the `display: none` if it is evaluated to `true`.

so your code should be like this

```
//1st Div
<div id="custInfoList" data-role="content"
    data-bind="foreach: customers, visible : customers().length > 0">
    <p data-bind="text: $data.info"></p>
</div>
//2nd Div
<div id="empty" data-role="content"
    data-bind="visible: customers().length === 0" style="display: none;">
    <p>No Customer Information</p>
</div>
```

and btw, it does not matter whether you use `visible` or `if` binding, as the problem is not with the binding itself.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you did wrongly in `//customers = {jsonData}`.

To update a ko.observable, you need to use `customers(jsonData)`, not `customers = jsonData`.

ko.observable() returns a function, the setter is `customers(newValue)` and the getter is `customers()`, you need to use function call explicitly in both setter and getter.